# Warning about using explicit keyword in a conversion operator

Tags: c++

so I have a class named `Date` which looks like this:

```cpp
class Date {
private:
    UINT month, day, year;
    std::string DateToString;
public:
    Date(UINT inMonth, UINT inDay, UINT inYear)
    : month(inMonth), day(inDay), year(inYear){}

    operator PCSTR() {
        //essentially just an ostream that takes strings inside it
        std::ostringstream formattedDate;
        //feed it and convert integers as well
        formattedDate << this->month << " / " << this->day << " / " << this->year;

        //get content of stream as a pointer with str() method
        //store the pointer in local var to avoid it to being invalidated after RET was hit and cout not able to display
        this->DateToString = formattedDate.str();
        return DateToString.c_str();//convert that ostringstream string to a PCSTR
    }
}
```

Note: I'm using Windows data types with `PCSTR` being a `const char*` and UINT an `unsigned int`.

Now this class serves as a date instantiation class: `Date test(1, 10, 2020)`, I've created the `operator PCSTR()` member method to be able to use it in `cout`, because the latter will use the most suited operator conversion to be able to display an object, and here we use `const char*/PCSTR` because `cout` does not have any problems displaying them. So if I do `cout << test;` it displays `1/10/2020`.

Now on my code editor it tells me `'operator const char *' must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions`, I don't understand, isn't that what we want, if I mark it explicit then I must cast the object, why can't I just leave it like that? What other conversions can happen with `const char*`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it really say "must be marked" or "should be marked" ?  Just asking because "must" can be confusing, but I definitely agree with "should", implicit conversion can be a pain in the ass

Comment: It say's `must` and on my book which uses a similar class, it recommends using it to avoid implicit conversions

Comment: Your code editor probably should _also_ say `'operator const char *' must not be marked explicit to allow intentional implicit conversions`.

Comment: You could perhaps avoid the problem by adding an overload for `operator<<` instead?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes I know, but in this example I wanted to use conversion operators

Comment: @Eljay Haha I agree :D

Comment: @idclev463035818 I agree that "should" would be better, but it's not technically incorrect, because it is true that you _"must"_ _to avoid unintentional implicit conversions_. There's a condition.

Comment: @TedLyngmo good point however the error I made is at the declaration order of the varaibles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of one unintentional implicit conversion here. If you were to accidentally write

```cpp
Date date;
// ...
if (date) { /* ... */ }
```

the compiler could first convert `date` to `const char*`, and then `const char*` to `bool`, and this would be a difficult-to-debug situation. The `explicit` operator protects against this situation.

There's a better way to define how your class should be printed to `std::cout`:

```cpp
class Date {
  // ...
  std::string toString() const {
    // ...
    return formattedDate.str();
  }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Date& date) {
  return out << date.toString();
}
```

If you must use a conversion operator, why not make it explicit and convert where needed? It would be easier to see from the code exactly what is happening.

```cpp
std::cout << static_cast<const char*>(date);
```

Comment: Thank you, really accurate example as well, I'm accepting in a minute :)

Comment: No rush, it's customary to give it a day to let other answers to come in.

Comment: An alternative to avoid the accidental conversion to `bool` would be to add `operator bool () = delete;`

Answer (score 1):

> Now on my code editor it tells me 'operator const char *' must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions

That's right. This is just a warning, but it's a good one!

> I don't understand, isn't that what we want

No!

> if I mark it explicit then I must cast the object

That's a good thing. It avoids accidents.

> why can't I just leave it like that?

You can if you want to. But I recommend that you don't.